# Proper way of setting fields in JavaScript using object prototype

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out the proper way to set up fields of my JavaScript object using prototype.

I can use the following:

```
function myData() {};
myData.prototype.a = null;
myData.prototype.b = null;
myData.prototype.c = null;

var data = new myData();
data.a = 1;
data.b = 2;
data.c = 3;
```

But, this does not seem to follow proper protocol for encapsulation.

Or, I can do as follows:

```
function myData() {
    this._a = null;
    this._b = null;
    this._c = null;
};

myData.prototype.__defineGetter__("a", function() {
    return this._a;
});

myData.prototype.__defineSetter__("a", function(val) {
        this._a = val;
});
```

This method seems overkill when my getters are just returning the private variable's value and not doing anything with it.

Also, is it correct to set the values to null in the constructor if I don't have the values until later?  i.e. - I set them later.

Comment: FYI, you often do NOT need to initialize something to `null`.  If one tries to read the value `myData.a` and `a` has not been initialized, the reader will just get `undefined` which often works just as well as `null`.  The test `if (myData.a)` works the same whether `a` was initialized to `null` or not inititalized at all.

Comment: I like to initialize my variables, but just for documentation purposes. But its just a matter of preferences.

Comment: BTW, per Javascript coding conventions, you should capitalize the first letter of your constructor (`MyData` vs. `myData`) to differentiate between constructors and procedural functions.

Comment: Do you need encapsulation or not? You seem to be unsatisfied both with and without it. Are your attributes public or strict private?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is a dynamic language, if you strictly don't need to encapsulate those properties you don't have to. Therefore the first example is perfectly fine.

Otherwise, if you need to encapsulate them, and you're in a ES5 compliant environment, you should use `get` and `set`, because `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` are deprecated and not standard (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/DefineGetter and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

An example:

```
function MyData() {
    // set to the prototype's value
    var a = this.a;
    var b = this.b;
    var c = this.c;

    Object.defineProperties(this, { 
        "a": {
            get : function(){ return a; },
            set : function(value) { a = value }
         },
         "b": {
            get : function(){ return b; },
            set : function(value) { b = value }
         },
         "c": {
            get : function(){ return c; },
            set : function(value) { c = value }
         }
    });
};

MyData.prototype.a = null;
MyData.prototype.b = null;
MyData.prototype.c = null;
```

See [Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

Comment: Why are you assigning each (a,b,c) variable to a corresponding "this.", e.g - var a = this.a;

Couldn't you just leave it as var a; instead of assigning a to this.a ?

Comment: As I wrote in the comment, I set each variables with the corresponding `prototype`'s value. In that way, if you do: `alert(new MyData().a)` you will get `null` that is the default value in the `prototype`. Otherwise, you will get `undefined`, and that is not consistent. In addition, in this way, if you change the `prototype` values with some other default value (e.g. a string) you  don't have to change the constructor, the new value will be inherit automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> am trying to figure out the proper way to set up fields of my JavaScript object

You should define what you mean by "proper".

```
>  var data = new myData();
>  data.a = 1;
>  data.b = 2;
>  data.c = 3;
```

In the above, you are adding `a`, `b` and `c` properties to the `data` object, you aren't modifying the value of `myData.prototype.a` (i.e. `data[[Prototype]].a`), etc.

> But, this does not seem to follow proper protocol for encapsulation.

You should explain what you mean by that, i.e., what you think the above should achieve.

[ snip `__defineGetter__`, `__defineSetter__` code ]

> This method seems overkill when my getters are just returning the private variable's value

"Private" variables, in the classic sense, don't exist in ECMAScript. You can emulate them with closures though. Have a look at the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth).